# Intersecting Lines on a Hyperbolic Paraboloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, solid-geometry

I have a hyperbolic paraboloid with the equation $f(x,y) = x^2-y^2 $

Given a point $P = (-1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}) $ , how do I find the two intersecting straight lines that lie on the surface and go through P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two systems of lines $\ell_a$ and $L_b$ making hyperbolic paraboloid $(HP)$ (with equation $z=x^2-y^2)$ a "doubly ruled" surface have the following equations  :

$$\ell_a \ \begin{cases}x-y=\dfrac{z}{a}\\x+y=a\end{cases}$$

$$ L_b \ \begin{cases}x-y=b\\x+y= \dfrac{z}{b}\end{cases}$$

It suffices then to express that $P$ belongs to each of the two families by replacing $x,y,z$ by its coordinates to get a (unique) value for $a$ and for $b$.

**Remark :** the fact that for example $\ell_a$ is a family of lines belonging to the $(HP)$ is due to the implication (by taking the product of equations) :

$$ \begin{cases}x-y=\dfrac{z}{a}\\x+y=a\end{cases} \ \implies  x^2-y^2=z$$

and one knows that properties expressed as **implications** corresponds to set **inclusions**, here $\ell_a \subset (HP)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn’t happen to know about the generators of the hyperbolic paraboloid $z=x^2-y^2$, you could proceed as follows: The tangent plane to the surface at $P$ is $x+\frac y2+\frac z2+\frac38=0$. The two lines that you’re looking for are the intersections of this plane with the surface. Solving the second equation for $z$ and substituting into the first produces $$x^2-y^2+2x+y+\frac34 = \frac14(2x+2y+1)(2x-2y+3)=0.$$ This is the equation of a pair of planes, and their intersections with the tangent plane will give you the two lines that lie on the surface. Since you already have a point on these lines, you just need their direction vectors, and those can be found by computing cross products of the plane normals. We have $\left(1,\frac12,\frac12\right)\times(2,2,0)=(-1,1,1)$ and $\left(1,\frac12,\frac12\right)\times(2,-2,0)=(1,1,-3)$, therefore the two lines are $$\left(-1,\frac12,\frac34\right)+t(-1,1,1)\text{ and } \left(-1,\frac12,\frac34\right)+t(1,1,3),$$ or in implicit form, $$x+1 = -{2y-1\over2}=-{4z-3\over4} \\ x+1 = {2y-1\over2} = {4z-3\over12}.$$